# How to verbalize $R[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, pronunciation

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $x$ be an indeterminate. Let $R[x]$ denote the ring of polynomials in $x$ with co-efficients in $R$. How to most efficiently read (i.e. pronounce) the symbol $R[x]$ while reading an abstract algebra text covering the topic?

Comment: I say "$R$ adjoin $x$."

Comment: I say "real polynomial ring."

Comment: @Austin: When someone says "let $R$ be a ring," you don't assume $\Bbb R$ (the reals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just say "R x".

Sometimes I have mathematical discussions via phone, and "R x" worked.

Comment: I second this. Or, if I'm working with something like $R[x]$, $R[[x]]$, $R(x)$, and $R((x))$, all in the same conversation I'd just say typographically what's happening: "R bracket x", "R double bracket x", "R parentheses x", "R double parentheses x"